# List Azure providers currently in use via API

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

I'm looking for an effective way to query the Azure resource manager API for all providers **currently** in use by my subscriptions - similar to what the resources.azure.com provides [providers listed via resource explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUYI9.png)

--EDIT START

An example, If I deploy a SQL DB into Azure, the Microsoft.SQL provider is used in the subscription. I deploy a Web App, Microsoft.Web lights up etc. etc.

I'm looking for a quick way to identity all the types of resources deployed within a subscription without having to get all the resource groups and the iterating through the resources and manually figuring it out. Or alternatively calling each provider independently and checking results - a slow and tedious task.

Since Microsoft is doing this in the resource explorer (resources.azure.com) I'm thinking I might be missing a trick

--EDIT ENDS

Using the standard API call I can get all resource providers registered, but can't find an effective way to query just those in use. Any ideas?

Comment: can you explain what exactly do you mean by "in use"?

Comment: Updated the question to clarify - I think, I hope

Comment: thanks, see if my answer below helps!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following REST API looks good for this purpose I guess:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list

It returns the resource list for any given subscription along with resource type. You can do a filter on it on the list.

[image]

Let me know if that helps!